# Redistribute rasapi32.dll?

Tags: c++, windows, winforms, winapi, visual-c++

I am creating a Dial-Up-Connection using Rasdial. To do this rasapi32.dll has to be linked.

My question here is can i redistribute this rasapi32.dll and rasapi32.lib with my package?

thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You certainly shouldn't need to distribute `rasapi32.lib` since you're linking to a DLL, and since `rasapi32.dll` is a standard Windows DLL, your users should have it on their machines already.

So my answer is "don't".

Comment: Yes you are right!! My worry here is if rasapi32.dll is not present or corrupted I will end-up in trouble??

Comment: yes you would. You could implement a crc and fail gracefully though, but it's common to just assume that the windows dlls work.

Comment: Yes, you should unless you know why you shouldn't.

Comment: If it's corrupt, the machine has far bigger problems.